# Получаю из буфера строку контрагентов. Как их преобразовать в список?

Tags: python

Задача быстро скопировать текст в буфер и обработать в командной строке через код, в зависимости от введенного символа. Проблема в том, что не получается перевести строку в список корректно. Это нужно, чтобы например сделать все заглавные только у первой буквы каждого контрагента. Может есть и другие варианты.

Например копирую из Excel список Контрагентов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если делаю через split, то получаю некорректное разбиение по всем пробелам и символы \r\n которые не нужны:
['ИП', 'Мубассаров', 'Дамир', 'Рафаильевич\r\nСПОРТКЛАСС\r\nИП', 'Фесенко-Навроцкий', 'Виктор', 'Владимирович\r\n(ФРАКТАЛ)\r\nИП', 'Часов', 'Валерий', 'Владимирович\r\nНТН\r\nЗАВОД', 'КРАСНЫЙ', 'ЯКОРЬ**\r\nЦЭЭВТ\r\n']

Comment: А split('\n') пробовали?

Comment: питоном файл открывать и считывать построчно, занося в массив?

Comment: Можно попробовать через https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 0):

Получив строку через `pyperclip.paste()` можно увидеть, что все строки в excel разделяются символами '\r\n', значит по ним мы и будем делать разделение строки:

```
s = pyperclip.paste().split('\r\n')
```

Comment: s = pyperclip.paste().split('\r\n')

Comment: Спасибо помогло